# Failing to evaluate correct path to zshrc file on new terminal window/tab

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, dotfiles

I'm trying to set up dotfiles/config, which I will be storing in github and using across multiple devices.

One of the things I want to achieve is that no matter where I clone my dotfiles, once I source it I will automatically have aliases like `updateDotfiles` that will pull the latest changes.

In order to achieve this, I tried putting `export DOTFILES_PATH=${0:P:h}` into my `.zshrc` so that I can automatically detect the path to my dotfiles folder.

This works exactly how I want it to if I run `source ~/.zshrc` (which is a symlink). What I've noticed is that when I first open a new terminal tab/window, `${0:P:h}` resolves to the wrong location. If I remove `:h` from it and echo the result I get `/Users/me/-zsh` and then if I run `source ~/.zshrc` I get `/Users/me/dotfiles-and-utils/.zshrc`

Is there something I'm missing here? How do I get it to work for both new windows and individual source runs?

In case it's relevant, I'm using iTerm2 and oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the following Q&A which set me off in the right direction (I won't pretend to understand what it's doing exactly) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249606/get-full-path-of-current-zsh-startup-file-e-g-zshrc-or-zshenv

Using ChatGPT I managed to tweak it to work how I wanted, the solution was to use `DOTFILES_PATH=$(dirname $(realpath ${(%):-%N}))`

`realPath` resolves any symlinks you have set up

In my case I wanted the directory I was storing my zshrc file, hence the use of `dirname`

Answer (score 0):

The zsh dotfiles are always looked up inside your $HOME, except if the variable `ZDOTDIR` is set. Hence you can find your dotfiles in `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}` and don't need to fiddle with $0.

The border case, which this would not catch, happens, if you modify `ZDOTDIR` somehow **inside** your dotfiles. But it would be insane to do this anyway, since ZDOTDIR must be defined at the time the zsh is started, so a later change wouldn't make sense anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be the solution I'm looking for. If I'm understanding it correctly, you'd need to clone the dotfiles, then set a ZDOTDIR variable manually to point to it?

My goal is to be able to clone the repo, run `source path/to/cloned/.zshrc` and from that point on everything is hooked up (including symlinks automatically set up). 

My answer below gets me a good part of the way there, I haven't tried automatically doing symlinks etc yet

Comment: Not sure why you need the cloned dotfiles, but if you make the dotfiles symlinks into the repo, then every time you update the repo, your dotfiles would already point to the correct location. In this case, setting ZDOTDIR is not necessary. An alternative is of course to start your new zsh with `ZDOTDIR` set to your `cloned` directory. Both approaches are feasible.